# Drupal Commerce: Get selected payment method programmatically

Tags: commerce

Is there any way to get programmatically the selected (by customer) payment method from the $order_wrapper variable in Drupal Commerce?

```php
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything built in, but you can use an `EntityFieldQuery` to grab the transaction(s) related to the order, and from there the payment type(s) used:

```
$query = new \EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_payment_transaction')
  ->propertyCondition('order_id', $order->order_id);

$results = $query->execute();
if (!empty($results['commerce_payment_transaction'])) {
  $transactions = entity_load('commerce_payment_transaction', array_keys($results['commerce_payment_transaction']));
  foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    $payment_method = $transaction->payment_method;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each payment method is a rule. Let's get the rule name than:

```
$payment_method = '';
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$r = explode('|', $order->data['payment_method']);
if (count($r) > 1){
  $rule = rules_config_load($r[1]);
  $payment_method = $rule->label;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Clive's answer above here's a rules condition set up for order is payment method.

Replace custom_commerce with the name of your module.

```
// custom_commerce.rules.inc

/**
 * Implements hook_rules_condition_info().
 */
function custom_commerce_rules_condition_info() {
  $conditions = array();

  // We have two or more payment methods we sometimes need to distinguish
  // between them.
  $conditions['custom_commerce_order_is_payment_method'] = array(
    'label' => t('Order is Payment Method'),
    'parameter' => array(
      'commerce_order' => array(
        'type' => 'commerce_order',
        'label' => t('Order'),
      ),
      'commerce_payment_method' =>array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => t('Payment Method'),
        'options list' => 'custom_commerce_payment_method_option_list',
      ),
    ),
    'group' => t('Custom Commerce'),
    'callbacks' => array(
      'execute' => 'custom_commerce_order_is_payment_method',
    ),
  );

  return $conditions;
}

/**
 * @param stdClass $order
 * @param string $expected_payment_method
 * @return bool
 */
function custom_commerce_order_is_payment_method($order, $expected_payment_method) {
  $query = new \EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_payment_transaction')
    ->propertyCondition('order_id', $order->order_id);

  $results = $query->execute();
  if (!empty($results['commerce_payment_transaction'])) {
    $transactions = entity_load('commerce_payment_transaction', array_keys($results['commerce_payment_transaction']));
    $transaction = end($transactions);
    $payment_method = $transaction->payment_method;
    return $payment_method === $expected_payment_method;
  }
  return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Returns key value pairs for the rules parameter drop down.
 */
function custom_commerce_payment_method_option_list() {
  $payment_methods = commerce_payment_methods();

  return array_map(function($v) {
    return $v['title'];
  }, $payment_methods);
}
```